# Cannot flush cache

Tags: google-chrome, mojave, dns

No matter what I do, I cannot get a web site to load after something changes with the DNS.

For instance, if `meh.blah.example.com` had a misconfigured DNS value and produced an `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` then fixing the DNS issue would work on everyone else's computer in the office within minutes of making the change, but on mine it is stuck forever. Days can go by and I'm effectively locked out of `meh.blah.example.com`. This is making performing dev-ops a major headache.

I've tried clearing it at the system level:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

I've tried clearing it in Chrome:

[image]

I've tried emptying the cache with a hard reload:

[image]

Pinging the domain:

```
ping: cannot resolve meh.blah.example.com: Unknown host
```

I've tried restarting my laptop.

Tried adding the Google DNS servers to my list:

[image]

Tried restarting DNSMasq:

```
brew services restart dnsmasq
```

Tried turning off Chrome's prediction service.

Trying on Safari doesn't fix the issue.

If I run `nslookup meh.blah.example.com 8.8.8.8` then Google confirms they can find it thru their DNS servers.

Is it possible some service is running on my Mac I can't see that is caching things?

Comment: Why have you got the first dns entry beginning with 127?

Comment: That is dnsmasq

Comment: Do you have the problem without dnsmasq?

Comment: Yep. Tried stopping the service, but no luck.